# How to populate an edit field with the computer host name?

Tags: installshield

I have an edit field that is set to a property.

Now I want that property initially populated with the host name.

Things I've tried so far:

```
 [%ComputerName]
 [ComputerName]
 {ComputerName}
```

None of which are working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear where you put that, but I'm assuming you mean the Property setting for the edit control. That won't work. Instead you need to associate the edit control with a regular property (so it can be updated), and set the value of that property with a Set Property custom action before this is shown.

Note that in order to support supplying the value from a command-line install (especially a silent one) you may wish to condition the Set Property action not to fire when the property already has a value.

Answer (score 0):

To set a default value for this control, make sure the property is a **public property by giving it a name that contains only uppercase letters**, use the Property Manager view to add the public property, and then assign to it the value of the default selection.

Before accessing this property first you need to set that property. You need to call either SetProperty CustomAction or you need to add that property in Property Manager.

And `[COMPUTER_NAME]` is the correct way to access it.